# App crash on android studio emulator everytime?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new on android studio and I'm following a tutorial to make a simple app. But i run the emulator and my app crash always. I think that is because this error:

[image]

And i don't know why i have that error, and how to solve it. Is this the reason my app is crashing? Anyone knows what should i do?

Comment: Hello, @Yesid Bejarano Camacho.
After you should update the gradle version, 'sync now' in app.gradle file.
If you want, I'll help you it.

Comment: Yes please!! I don´t see the app.gradle file

Comment: I find the file and sync it, but still have the error and the app is still crashing

Comment: you should insert `buildToolsVersion` options.

Comment: Please see the stacktrace in the `LogCat` view and post it here. It will help debug the issue

Comment: @ShobhitPuri The thing is that the stacktrace shows a lot of errors and does not stops, just keeps showing and its confusing

Comment: Did you try filtering by only `error` type and then by your application package name? That way you'll only see the error related to your package and not other system errors.

Comment: please post the logcat

Comment: @YesidBejaranoCamacho can you check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove that error you can add this below your dependencies and sync the Project. However, as far as I can see, you are not sure what is causing the crashes. Check for errors and get back with some info from the logs

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion "27.+"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This solve the error. But the app is still crashing. Thanks anyway

Comment: cannot find symbol DependencyResolveDetails how to add DependencyResolveDetails

Answer (score 0):

android

```
{
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}
```

and

```
dependencies
{
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

change after resync then your problem was solved. can try this one.

Answer (score -1):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "yabej.thecorner"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        ... ...
    }
    buildTypes {
       ... ... 
    }
... ...
```

you should add `buildToolsVersion` options, sync it again, plz.
notes: `buildToolsVersion` can be select as any version.

Comment: I did it, and get this error: "The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools."

Comment: yeah, now you should update `26.0.2` to `28.0.2`. and gradle plugin too.